Почему Intellij idea настаивает на применении unnamed variables?
В Java 22 появилась возможность назвать неиспользуемую переменную нижним подчёркиванием (JEP 456).
У меня есть такая строчка:
go.addActionListener(e -> ui.setVisible(false));

И  теперь среда разработки выдаёт предупреждение:

Parameter 'e' is never used

С предложением заменить e на _:
go.addActionListener(_ -> ui.setVisible(false));

Стоит ли так делать? Каков смысл этого? По мне так когда видишь это, то смотришь и несколько секунд не можешь понять, что это такое вообще...

"Почему Intellij idea настаивает на применении unnamed variables?" --- я думаю потому, что так он настроен. Можно поменять в настройках наверняка на то поведение, которое приемлемо для разработчика/группы разработчиков/организации

@АлексейШиманский раз оно так по умолчанию настроено, то это, наверное, не просто так было сделано? То есть в этом смысл должен быть?

@Зонтик да вряд ли. Это как при использовании типов в switch Idea предлагает неиспользуемые заменить на ingored.

@Зонтик настроено просто на новую фичу, вот и всё. Разным людям могут понадобиться разные настройки. Никто не запрещает их менять. Иначе бы там это было вшито жёстко без возможности изменения

@Зонтик, см. IntelliJ IDEA Blog :: Drop the Baggage: Use ‘_’ for Unnamed Local Variables and Patterns in Java 22

Использовать ли unnamed variables – дело вкуса. Задумка была в том, чтобы можно было показать намерение не использовать переменную. Это может иметь смысл, если есть какой-нибудь длинный foreach, например, где видно далеко не сразу, что переменная нигде не понадобилась.
Правда среда предлагает это делать везде, что не всем может понравиться. В данном случае, по моему сугубо личному мнению, нижнее подчёркивание выглядит коряво.
Но когда я попробовал отключить проверку (нажал disable inspection), отключилась проверка обычных бесполезных переменных, созданных случайно, например в коде ниже:
public void doSomthing() {
    int x = 3; //Переменная не используется и была создана по ошибке
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar();
    foo.baz();
}

Поэтому в данном случае пришлось просто подавить предупреждение. Нажимаем правой кнопкой мыши по предупреждению -> Show quick-fixes -> ... и выбираем suppres for statement, либо suppress for statement with comment.
Скриншот:

